# How can I extract the numbers in the file using sed or any other tool?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a file that has this format

> [ 2014/05/01 10:48:26 | 13963 | DEBUG  ] It took 11.16837501525879
>   seconds to complete the process

So I have thousands of lines like this and I would like to "extract" the `11.16837501525879` part
I tried:

```
 sed -e 's/^.* (\d+\.\d*)/\1/g' logfile.txt > out.txt
```

but I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 8):

`sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions by default and BREs don't know about `\d`. Here are some other approaches:

1. `sed`

   ```
   sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*).*?/\1/' logfile.txt > outfile.txt
   ```

   The `-r` is needed to avoid having to escape the parentheses.
2. `perl`

   ```
   perl -pe 's/.* (\d+\.*\d*).*/$1/' logfile.txt > outfile.txt
   ```
3. `grep`

   ```
   grep -Po '.* \K\d+\.*\d*' logfile.txt > outfile.txt
   ```

These all use your basic approach, which fill find *all* sets of digits in the line that are preceded by a space. Depending on how many sets of numbers can appear on the line, if your input lines are always of the format you show, a safer approach would be:

```
grep -Po 'took \K\d+\.*\d*' logfile.txt
```

Comment: Actually, without `/g` this will find the last set of digits preceded by a space. The `grep`one is the one that will find them all.

Comment: @JosephR. yes, even with the `g` it will not do what the OP wanted, hence the `grep` one.

Answer (score 4):

Grouping parentheses must be backslashed in sed. Also, sed doesn't support `\d`. Moreover, you should also remove the words *after* the number:

```
sed -e 's/^.* \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]*\) .*/\1/g'
```

BTW, are you sure the dot is always present, but the decimal numbers are optional? `12.` doesn't seem as an expected value.

Comment: It worked +1! BTW what does `-e` do then if I need to escape everything?

Comment: If the decimal were optional then `sed -e 's/.*took \([0-9.]*\).*/\1/g'` would work well.

Comment: @Jim: Nothing. That's why you can omit it in some versions of `sed`. Also, some versions support `-r` in which you don't have to backslash `()` and `+` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk to print the 11th column (determined by space separation).

```
awk '{ print $11 }' logfile.txt > output
```